# Searching for substring knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I am trying to filter through an array and check to see if any of titles in my array includes what the user is searching for. However, when I run the function it only seems to check if the search exactly matches the title not if a sub string is included.

**JS**

```
var viewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.filter = ko.observable('');
self.locationList = ko.observableArray(model);
self.filterList = function(){

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(model, function(location) {

       if(self.filter().includes(location.title)){
          console.log(location.title)
       }

    });
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input data-bind="textInput: filter, event:{keyup: filterList}"
    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter Places"
    aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="test">
    <button id="basic-addon2">Filter</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this part `if(self.filter().includes(location.title)){`

Here you are checking if searched key contains one of the titles in array. Instead you should check otherwise

```
if(location.title.includes(self.filter())){
```

You can use simple `.filter` and `.includes` for that

```
var filterdList = self.locationList.filter(e=> e.includes(self.filter()))
```

Comment: Thats what I just did and it seems to be working thank you for the reply.

Comment: Glad to know that. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it resolved your query :)

Comment: Gotta wait to give the check